# MESI cost of sharing data across multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mesi

I want to measure the cache coherency (MESI) cost of reading a variable which another thread is writing to. I came up with the following test, but it reports the read only takes 2 cycles on average:

```
// NB I used Microsoft's compiler so you will need your own rdtscp()

#include <thread>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>


int global;

void write(){
    uint64_t counter = 0;
    while (true){
        global = counter;
        counter++;
    }
}

void read(){
    uint64_t n = 100000000;
    uint32_t x;
    uint64_t start = __rdtscp(&x);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        volatile int copy = global + i;
    }
    uint64_t finish = __rdtscp(&x);
    std::cout << (finish - start) / n << " cycles per read" << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    std::thread thread1(write);
    std::thread thread2(read);

    thread1.detach();
    thread2.join();
}
```

Is my test incorrect? Could somebody please help me improve it?

EDIT: My understanding is MESI has nothing to do with atomic types in C++. MESI ensures that cache lines are coherent across multiple CPU cores. Therefore I have not used atomics in this test.

This is very similar to the false sharing problem, where I would have a second global variable, they both occupy the same cache line but different threads write to each. As each variable is written by one thread, why would we use atomics?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90180/discussion-on-question-by-mezamorphic-mesi-cost-of-sharing-data-across-multiple).